# Does Apache's HttpClient manage inlined URL authentication?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm not seeing it in docs, good to check here:

*Does `HttpClient` manage HTTP authorization (preemptive or otherwise) with credentials in the URL line?*

**For instance:** `http://foo:bar@hostname/Hello/World` inlines username `foo` and password `bar` for authorization (actually authentication, but just using same nomenclature).

**Basically:**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://foo:bar@hostname/Hello/World");
```

**vs.:**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getState().setCredentials(
          new AuthScope( /* stuff */ );
        , new UsernamePasswordCredentials("foo","bar");
);
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://foo:bar@hostname/Hello/World");
get.setDoAuthentication(true);
```

I tried it no joy. 

*Am I something wrong?*